# MathJax Greasemonkey script

Tags: discussion, mathjax

I'm now finding it impossible to write certain questions and answers without MathJax, so while we're waiting I put together a GreaseMonkey script that renders LaTeX here on HSM. It's just the well-known [bookmarklet](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~robjohn/math/mathjax.html) but in GM script form.

## [MathJaxForHSM.user.js](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/93726541/MathJaxForHSM.user.js)

**If you've never used GreaseMonkey** or don't have it installed, [this](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/dynamic.html) MathJax page has recommendations for each browser (scroll down to the *MathJax and GreaseMonkey* section). At least under Firefox, all you should need to do once it's installed is click on the link to the script and you'll be prompted to install it.

Hopefully it works on your browser like it does on mine (I'm using Firefox).

**If you don't want to use GreaseMonkey**, remember that the aforementioned [bookmarklet](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~robjohn/math/mathjax.html) exists. All you should need to do is add the link to your bookmark just like that page says, and then click it while looking at page here to render LaTeX.

I'd also like to discuss whether we should, as many are doing, use LaTeX regardless of whether or not MathJax has been implemented yet, or hold off and use other means until then. Last night someone converted all the LaTeX in my question to Unicode. I approved the edit, but I think in the long term we might be better off using LaTeX right away, especially now that we have this GM script (assuming it works) and the bookmarklet to tide us over. We don't know how long it'll take to implement MathJax and we don't want to end up with three months worth of content that'll need to be edited to insert LaTeX.

Comment: I definitely vote for using LaTeX right away, both for the back-edit problem, and to accumulate yet more evidence of the need for MathJax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to install Greasemonkey scripts. MathJax support is clearly needed here, *so…*

$$
\Huge MathJax: ACTIVATED
$$